# Need Voltage Converter for LED strip power

Tags: power-supply, voltage, led, converter

As an electronics hobbyist, I'm currently exploring a project where I have taken out the LED backlight strip from a LCD TV. I checked by supplying DC power to the LED strip and it takes around 75 V, 1.25 A.

I am looking to power the LED strip by a regular 110 V outlet. For this, first I thought of building something using resistors, but in that case voltage drop can be achieved but the output will still be AC (as just using resistors won't convert AC to DC).

Would be helpful if anyone can let me know how I can get 75 V, 1.25 A by inputting regular 110 V.

Comment: Use the power supply from the TV? What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: I am trying to power LED Backlight strip taken out from LCD tv like this: https://i.ibb.co/G2K6HcY/FZ6-DVVBJCUUJ358.jpg  using a regular 110v output socket in wall. For that I need to know what to use to build voltage converter, adapter, ac to dc converter/ current reducer etc? Thee LED strip i checked when power on uses 110 V , 1.25 A current

Comment: Yes, you said that, but why? This is not a trivial power supply to build and not a beginner project. If you just want an illuminated panel it's probably easier and cheaper to buy one designed for a ceiling that comes with its own supply.

Comment: Thats how I am learning DIY, experiment creates invention which further creates needs. This process proves to be an ideal learning ground. I am trying to power the LED strip light by mounting it under the cabinet or wall. What I am aware of and fgured out is the the following can be made to convert standard 110 V 15A AC outlet into 75 V 1,5A DC -- 1) Bridge Rectifier ,  2) AC To DC Voltage Converter  ,  3) AC to DC Switching Power Supply. The first 2 are not that complex and can be made if I have the circuit and components. However I dont know how to achieve specific 75 V and 1.25 A current

Comment: Building a switched mode supply that connects directly to the mains is most definitely not a beginner project. You also need to know exactly how that LED strip needs to be driven - whether it has any sort of current limit built in or whether the supply needs to drive it with constant current. A look at the circuit of the TV you took it from might help.